# How can one trace out polaritonic degrees of freedom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I have read the paper "Steady state entanglement between hybrid light-matter qubits", [arXiv:0711.1830v2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1830).
There, writers obtained density operator in matrix form after solving steady state equation (13). I want to know how one can trace out polaritonic degree of freedom of one of two cavities.

Comment: Hi kate, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is a very good question. I'm not sure whether anyone who frequents this site has the expertise to answer it, but I hope so.

Comment: Are you asking how you reduce the 4 by 4 density matrix for 2 qubits into the 2 by 2 matrix for one qubit? Or do you want something more?

Comment: yes, that is what exactly I want. But in this case, when we want to find reduced density matrix for each of these polaritons I guess we should consider influence of entanglement. I mean each of these polaritons should not have equal density matrix.